# how to convert angular UTC timestamp to local timestamp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, timestamp, utc

Is there a function or a way to convert a UTC timestamp to a local time timestamp?

I am passing the timestamp to angular moments but the timestamp from the server is in UTC.

Comment: What does the UTC timestamp look like?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that a JavaScript timestamp (i.e., a value retrieved from `Date.now()` or `date.getTime()`) has no timezone associated with it. It is simply the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. In JavaScript, there is no such thing as *local* timestamp. In order to convert a timestamp into a date that use the machine-local timezone you simply do the following:

```
let myTimestamp = Date.now();
let dateInLocalTimezone = new Date(myTimestamp);
```

Comment: You're right. I was being a bit loose with my terminology. I will correct above. A JavaScript timestamp is simply the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. There is no timezone associated with it. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether the question is about parsing or formatting, or both, or whether you want functions only within angular.js or ionic-framework. The following is for plain ECMAScript.

> Is there a function or a way to convert a UTC timestamp to a local time timestamp?

Yes, however it depends on what the timestamp is. If it's a string in ISO 8601 extended format like "2017-03-20T15:45:06Z" then in modern browsers it can be parsed by the built-in parser using either the Date constructor (to create a Date object) or Date.parse (to produce a time value).

If it's in any other format, then it should be manually parsed, either with a small function or library.

Once you have a Date object, it can be formatted in the host timezone using Date methods, see *[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1%7C20.3690)*

e.g.

```js
var s = "2017-03-20T12:00:00Z"
var d = new Date(s);

// Browser default, implementation dependent
console.log(d.toString());

// Use toLocaleString with options, implementation dependent and problematic
console.log(d.toLocaleString(undefined,{
  weekday: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
}));
```